# py2exe font module not available

Tags: python, pygame, py2exe

my main files:

setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import pygame._view
import py2exe
import pygame

setup(console=['game.py'])
```

game.py:

```
import pygame, sys, random
import pygame._view
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([550,450])
screen.fill([255,255,255])
fnt = pygame.font.Font(None, 35)
wrt = fnt.render('Help', True, [0,0,0])
screen.blit(wrt,[235,103])
pygame.display.update()

start = True
while start:
   for event in pygame.event.get():
       if event.type == QUIT: 
          pygame.quit()
```

then i open CMD and type :"python setup.py py2exe"
when its done, i try to run the game.exe file 
its shows me an error:

http://i40.tinypic.com/10cqb11.png

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I run across the same problem and I found the exactly solution here: http://pygame.org/wiki/Pygame2exe

just observe you dont need to run this code with 'py2exe' argument since its already there:

```
sys.argv.append('py2exe')
```